# Why would light not heat a body if the source of the light is the same temperature as that body?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I'm specifically looking at the case of the Sun's corona emitting light that then heats up other bodies on Earth. These bodies can never attain a higher temperature than the Sun's corona.

I know the obvious answer as to why this is is that the second law of thermodynamics says so. But the fact that the light emitted somehow encodes within it the temperature of the thing that emits it is what is strange to me. Are there not bodies of different temperatures that emit the same frequencies of light? Is there some deeper set of statistical mechanics taking place such that the second law of thermodynamics holds?

It makes sense for bodies directly interacting to end up at the same temperature, and at the microscopic scale this would seem to happen because of electrostatic interactions between the bodies. Whichever atom in an atom-atom interaction has a greater kinetic energy will impart kinetic energy on the atom with a lower kinetic energy until equilibrium. A bit of handwaving, I'm sure, because we are considering classical atom-atom interactions, but it makes quite good sense and probably isn't completely off. However, light seems to somehow encode the temperature of what emitted it, and I can't explain how the second law of thermodynamics holds with it.

Why is it that the light emitted by a body of a certain temperature will not heat up a body of the same or greater temperature? Answers I'd like would sort of explain the interactions taking place such that the second law makes some sort of sense, perhaps with Newton's laws, statistical mechanics, Maxwell's equations... whatever else makes sense would be appreciated, really.

Comment: Is that truly the case? Any source? I think using a lens large enough, you'll be able to obtain local temperatures higher than at the source.

Comment: "the fact that the light emitted somehow encodes within it the temperature of the thing that emits it is what is strange to me."  That is what the black body radiation spectrum represents.

Comment: @SF. Doesn't your statement violate second law?

Comment: @Zero: Entropy in the whole system increases. Localized decreases of entropy are not violating second law of thermodynamics. (otherwise existence of life would be violating it)

Comment: @SF. I asked that only because your statement sounds like it is possible to transfer heat from colder to hotter body, without any external input of work.

Comment: @Zero: It is certainly impossible through common convection and conduction, but radiation only "averages the temperatures" in general case through having the irradiated area and emissive areas being roughly equal, and emission and irradiation roughly proportional to temperatures. The input of work is necessary, but not necessarily external (what's 'external' depends on how you define borders of the system).

Comment: A simple example experiment: inside an insulated box place a peltier cell with a resistor attached to its terminal, the cell sitting on a block of ice and has a cup of liquid nitrogen on top. As heat from the ice cube travels to liquid nitrogen through the cell, the resistor heats way above temperature of both. This is an isolated system, all work is expended within it, but localized rise in entropy as ice freezes deeper and LN2 evaporates, Similarly low-energy high-volume emission can be transformed into high-energy low-volume, through *little* extra work (though rarely does so spontaneously)

Comment: @SF. In your very first comment in which lens is used to obtain local temperature higher than source, where does work input come in?

Comment: @Zero: Radiative cooling of the emitter material: electrons in atoms moving from higher energy orbitals to lower energy while emitting photons. In the heated material electrons won't be able to move to even higher energy states regardless of the number of incoming (low energy) photons, but as a large number of whole multi-atomic particles gain kinetic energy in a small volume, this is equivalent to a massive temperature rise.

Comment: Think: 1 square meter of material with 1% of atoms in excited state (suspended in void) emits photons at 1 square millimeter of material with 10% of atoms in excited state (through a lens). The 1mm^2 energy output is insignificant over the area million times larger. Meanwhile the 1m^2 going towards ground state by dissipating its energy all around increases entropy vastly more than the part of its photons that reach the 1mm^2 decrease it.

Comment: @SF. Sorry not convinced. I will think it through. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a simple example of the Sun heating some body e.g. the Earth.

The key point to remember is that light ray trajectories are symmetric i.e. for every light ray that leaves the Sun and hits the Earth a light ray from the Earth can move along the same path in the opposite direction and hit the Sun. So at the same time that the Sun is heating the Earth the Earth is heating the Sun.

This symmetry means that for any pair of bodies there will be a net flow of radiant energy from the hotter one to the colder one. So the Sun cannot heat the Earth, or anything else, to a higher temperature than its own surface.

Answer (score 1):

Look into black body radiation. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#Explanation

The body being heated is radiating too, so for it to increase in temperature radiation in must be greater than radiation out. (possible, but doesn't tend to occur in naturally - e.g. in astronomy).